# Authentication Required Popup box for vTiger CMS

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, vtiger

I'm using **vTiger CRM 5.4.0**

It was working fine but i have changed and updated my server and simply copy paste and upload previous back from old server along with DB...
but it always shows me Popup box for **"Authentication Required"** on each page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this message is most probably due to the use of [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on the server side. 
This has nothing to do with Vtiger and it's something you (or the person in charge of managing your server) needs to set on the web server side (may be Apache, IIS, or others).

If your interest is to disable the request of username and password, you should edit the server configuration. In case of IIS, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837139) is a good starting point. In case of Apache web server, see [this link](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth).

Otherwise, you should check with the manager of your server for your username and password. The popup should not come up once the right combination has been entered.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is Plesk. Plesk automaticaly creates a virtual directory named "test". This directory holds the Vtiger logo. Loading the logo causes the permission issue.

Solution: rename or delete the virual directy "test" in Plesk.